# I watched a youtube tutorial about themes but they only showed it with system colors and i want an rgb color how do i fix this?

Tags: c#

So I watched a youtube tutorial on how to make themes they only showed how to do it with system colors I want to use RGB to set mine how can I fix this issue

```
if(Clockworks.Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == ("Default")
                this.BackColor = SystemColors = 25; 25; 25;
```

I tried to fix it myself but im not that good at C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you want (and the jury-is-out on that). You will need [Color.FromRgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates a new Color structure by using the specified sRGB color
>   channel values.

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromRgb(25, 25, 25);
```